# What's the easiest way to create a managed visualiser in C#?

Tags: c#, debugging, natvis

I have a background in C++ and recently I started working in C#.

I have written following pieces of code (in Visual Studio):

```
var list_Loads = database.GetData<Load>().ToList();
var test_list = list_Loads.Where(o => (o.Name.Substring(0, 3) == "123")).ToList();
```

When I run the program and I move my mouse over both lists, first I get the count, which is very useful, but when I ask for the entries, this is what I get:

```
0 : namespace.Load
1 : namespace.Load
2 : namespace.Load
...
```

Not very useful, as you can imagine :-)

So my question: how can I show the `Name` attributes of those objects?

I thought: no problem. I have a background in native visualisers, so it should be rather easy to turn this into useful information, but then it comes:
In order to alter the way that those objects are represented, there is the first proposal to add a `[DebuggerDisplay]` "tag" to the definition of that class in source code.
However, as those classes are part of a framework I'm just referring to, I don't have access to the source code and hence I can't modify this.

Then I found another solution, which comes down to: "Write an entire C# project, debug, test and install it and it might work" (see [documentation on "Custom visualisers of data" on the Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-visualizers-of-data?view=vs-2017)).
I almost choked in my coffee: writing an entire project, just for altering the view of an object??? (While, in C++, you just create a simple `.natvis` file, mention the classname and some configuration, launch `.nvload` and that's it.

Does anybody know a simple way to alter the appearance of C# object, without needing to pass through the whole burden of creating an entire C# project?

By the way, when I try to load a `natvis` file in Visual Studio immediate window, this is what I get:

```
.nvload "C:\Temp_Folder\test.natvis"
error CS1525: Invalid expression term '.'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP (my emphasis):

> In order to alter the way that those objects are represented, there is the first proposal to add a [DebuggerDisplay] "tag" to the definition of that class in source code.
> However, as those classes are part of a framework I'm just referring to, **I don't have access to the source code and hence I can't modify this.**

> Does anybody know a simple way to alter the appearance of C# object, without needing to pass through the whole burden of creating an entire C# project?

If you just want to specify `[DebuggerDisplay]` on a type, you don't have to have access to the source code.  You can make use of `[assembly:DebuggerDisplay()]` and control how a type appears in the debugger.  The only downside is that `[assembly:DebuggerDisplay()]` naturally only affects the *current* assembly whose code your mouse is hovering over.  If you wish to use the customised display in other assemblies that you own, then you must repeat the `[assembly:DebuggerDisplay()]` definition.

Here's an easy before-and-after example with `DateTime`.  I picked `DateTime` because we generally don't have access to the source code and it has some interesting properties:

```
 var items = new List<DateTime>
 {
     DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
     DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
     DateTime.Now
 };
```

...which on my machine defaults to:

[image]

Maybe I'm fussy and I just want to see:

- *Day of the week* and
- *Day of the year*

...I can do that via:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

[assembly: DebuggerDisplay("{DayOfWeek} {DayOfYear}", Target = typeof(DateTime))]
```

...which results in:

[image]

Example:

```
namespace DebuggerDisplayTests
{
    public class DebuggerDisplayTests
    {
        public DebuggerDisplayTests()
        {
            var items = new List<DateTime>
            {
                DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
                DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
                DateTime.Now
            };
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

### Overrides

`[assembly:DebuggerDisplay()]` can also be used as a means to *override* pre-existing `[DebuggerDisplay]` on a 3-rd party type.  Don't like what style they have chosen?  Is the type showing far too much information? Change it with `[assembly:DebuggerDisplay()]`.

Comment: ... but now that I think of it: while working with C++, it was my job to analyse memory dumps while now I'm doing development. If, however, I might need to analyse memory dumps too, the `[assembly:DebuggerDisplay]` trick might not work (as I won't be able to modify the source code). I have just tried to launch `System.Diagnostics.DebuggerDisplayAttribute("Name=[{Name}], ID=[{Id}]", Target = typeof(namespace.UnitLoad))` in the immediate window but that wasn't a big success :-)

Comment: @Dominique _"I have just tried to launch ... in the immediate window but that wasn't a big success :-)"_ - LOL :D